# How to concatenate a user inputted string using HTML input tag

Tags: html, forms

I am doing the following:

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search">
 <div>
   <input type="text" name="q" id="corners">
 </div>
 <div>
   <input type="submit" value="Google Image Search">
 </div>
</form>
```

However, I want to add additional default text to the URL after the user's input like this:

`https://www.google.com/search?q=searchterm&some-additional-text`

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using another input which is hidden?

Comment: No, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="" value="" style="display: none;">`. However, then you would have to deal with the `&name=` part, so it's probably not the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using the following:

```html
   <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" name="test">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses JavaScript to concatenate `https://www.google.com/search?q=`, the input value and any additional text, then assigns that string to the `action` attribute of the form, before submitting the form.

```js
function submitForm() {
  var form = document.getElementById("form");
  var search = document.getElementById("corners").value;
  var additional = "&";
  form.setAttribute("action", "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + search + additional);
  form.submit();
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" id="form">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="q" id="corners">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Google Image Search" onclick="submitForm()">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I am trying to build this out using pure HTML.